# using a login page for spring security

Tags: spring, security, authentication

i am a beginner with spring security. i wanted to try using a login.jsp to authenticate. the login page is showed, but when i authenticate, it doesn't go to the default-target-url. here is my code:
spring-security-context.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">
```

```
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login.jsp*" access="permitAll"/> 
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/Home.jsp*" access="hasRole('ROLE_FORMATEUR')" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_FORMATEUR')"/>

    <security:form-login login-page='/login.jsp' 
                        default-target-url='/Home.jsp'/>
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:user-service>
            <security:user name="xxx" password="123" authorities="ROLE_FORMATEUR,ROLE_ADMIN" />
            <security:user name="yyy" password="456" authorities="ROLE_FORMATEUR" />
        </security:user-service>
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

login.jsp

```
 <body>
<form method="post" action="j_spring_security_check">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td> Login: </td>
            <td> <input type="text" name="j_username"> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> Mot de passe: </td>
            <td> <input type="password" name="j_passxord"> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
            <td colspan="2"> <input type="submit" value="Valider">
            <input type="reset" value="Annuler"> </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<input type="password" name="j_passxord">` chance this to `<input type="password" name="j_password">`

Comment: Thank you. I changed it and it works now. i am sorry it was just an inattention mistake. Now i will try to log in with users from a database...